# Redirect с изменением нескольких параметров url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

модель

```
public class Filter
{
    public string id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    private string _id = "all";
}
```

контроллер

```
public ActionResult Detail(Filter fltr) {
    List<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
    /*.....*/
    ViewBag.date = ddl; //
    ViewBag.filter = fltr;
    return View();
}
```

http://baseurl/contr/detail/all?date=2015-11-11&type=dynamic

На странице есть `@html.DropDownList("date", null, new { @class = "my-class"})`

Как сделать, что бы при событии onchange на dropdownlist изменялась дата в url и происходил redirect, используя модель filter?

Comment: о модели могли сразу написать? а то я вам уже ответ накатал

Comment: да, про модель фильтра забудте, вы же отправляете данные через `GET`, так что давайте использовать отдельные параметры в контроллере...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так:

```
$('#date').on('change', function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   $(location).attr('href', 'http://baseurl/contr/detail/all?date='+val+'&type=dynamic');
});
```

**UPD:** Ответ неучитывает пожелание ТС об отправки модели через querystring GET запроса

Comment: Спасибо! Долго пытался пытался пытался